# MongoDB: id созданного обьекта методом save

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection(tableName).save({}, {}, (err, doc)=>{
    console.log(`Saved doc: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
})
```

выводит:

```
Saved doc: {"ok":1,"n":1}
```

Запись в базе успешно создается.
Как теперь узнать с каким идентификатором оно сохранилось то?)

Хочу сделать чтобы меня не волновало есть ли запись в базе, или же создается новая. Для этой цели вроде как и предназначен save()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего случая можно использовать `insert` вместо `save`, без указания `_id` они работают одинаково. Но, в отличии от `save`, `insert` возвращает в том числе `id` для вставленных в коллекцию документов:

```
  db.collection(tableName).insert({}, (err, doc)=>{
    console.log(`Saved doc: ${JSON.stringify(doc.insertedIds[0])}`)
  });
```

Если же во вставляемом документе будет указан `_id`, то он будет либо вставлен (если документа с таким `_id` ещё нет), либо произойдет ошибка. Также у `insert` есть параметр флажок `upsert`, если он установлен, то при совпадении `_id` будет переписан документ, вместо ошибки.

`insert` также позволяет вставлять сразу несколько документов, если передать ему первым аргументом массив из документов. Поэтому в результате возвращается массив `_id` (для случая со вставкой одного документа просто берем первый элемент: `insertedIds[0]`).